# Url wordpress rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

In wordpress i have created a custom page called `mail.php` inside a folder `form_support`, my original url is `http://exemple.com/form_support/mail.php`
i created htaccess file with rewriting rule :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mail$ /form_support/mail.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

i upload the htaccess file inside the folder `form_support` but when i call the `mail.php` page i dont get the rewrite url as mentioned above

```
http://exemple.com/mail
```

is there any thing i have missed ?

my files

```
-wp-admin
-wp-content
-wp-includes
-form_support
    - mail.php
    - .htaccess
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a folder.

And create a file inside your theme with starting content of following one

```
  <?php
    /* 
      Template Name: Mail Page 
     */
      // here your mail page content. 
  ?>
```

Now goto backend and `pages-> Add New`. 
Title your page  and select a Template `Mail Page`.

Now you can write your code on the template file.  It will take effect.